# Power Shell does not like command

Tags: windows-7, command-line-interface, powershell

Any ideas what I did wrong here? I copied this script from a tutorial and get this error....

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-Service | Where-Object ($_.status -eq "running")

Where-Object : Cannot bind parameter 'FilterScript'. Cannot convert value "False" to type "System.Management.Automation
.ScriptBlock". Error: "Invalid cast from 'System.Boolean' to 'System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock'."
At line:1 char:27
+ Get-Service | Where-Object <<<<  ($_.status -eq "running")
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Where-Object], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WhereObjectCommand
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using {} instead of parentheses around your argument.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee177028.aspx

> Take careful note of the syntax. To begin, the where clause is enclosed within curly braces; in addition, the $_ notation is used to represent the default object (that is, the object being transferred across the pipeline).

Answer (score 5):

You need to use { instead of (

```
Get-Service | Where-Object {$_.status -eq "running"}
```

Comment: Holocryptic beat you by a minute :(. Still gave You a plus 1. Thanks!